# Android Transition from Component to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I know this is possible, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have an Android app that shows a grid of squares which is created using grid adapters, viewgroups, and a fragment. When the user clicks a block in the grid, it shows a new fragment with additional related information.

I was able to get a transition to occur when I click the first block, but it just flips the entire grid rather than doing a flip transition with the new fragment. I would also like to ask how you create a zoom transition?

**GridViewFragment** - The following is code snippets from one of the documents that create the grid.

```
@AfterViews
void AfterViews() {
    context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
    gridAdapter.setDataResponse(dashboard.resp);
    gridview.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            DashboardGridViewItem item = (DashboardGridViewItem) v;
            flipCard(app.getGridInfo()[position], item.getImageJSON());
        }
    });

    /*mGoogleApiClient.connect();*/
}

@UiThread(propagation = UiThread.Propagation.REUSE)
void flipCard(DataObject data, ResponseEntity<String> image) {
    String fragmentType = data.getTitle();

            dashboard.fragment = Fragment_.builder().build();
            dashboard.fragment.setmData(data);
            dashboard.fragment.setImageJSON(image);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = dashboard.getSupportFragmentManager();
            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.card_flip_left_in, R.anim.card_flip_left_out);

            transaction.replace(dashboard.fragmentContainer.getId(), dashboard.summaryFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
.... (the rest of the function is just switch cases for different grid blocks, so it looks like what's pasted above)
```

This is where the fragment container is declared on the dashboard (which is accessed in the code above).

```
@ViewById
public FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
```

As I mentioned above, the issue is that the transition is happening after the block is clicked, but it controls the entire grid and then shows the new fragment once the animation is over. I want the animation to happen to the fragment.